# helper method returning true when it should return false

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my application, 'Users' has_many 'Jobs', through 'applications'

I'm trying to create a helper method has_job(@user, @job). Where, it will return true if the user has already associated itself to a particular job.

When I'm doing this though, if I apply to 1 job, then it returns true for all other jobs.

Why is this happening?

This is what my helper method looks like ->

```
  def has_job(user,current_job)
    if user.applications.any?
      user.applications.each do |application|
        return true if application.job_id = current_job.id 
      end
    end
    false
  end
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`return true if application.job_id == current_job.id`

The single `=` would cause it to return `true` every time.

Comment: Ah! thanks TheDude, okay, it returned false :D. (will click the accept button in 10 mins)